# Remove white space from string using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a string:

result = " is programming that manages the execution of programs written in any of several supported languages."

I want to remove white space at the beginning of a sentence.
How I can do it?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Trim(result)` it will remove all white spaces at the beginning and at the end of a string

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by using Trim(String) in VBA (for trimming left and right spaces) or use LTrim(String) for only trimming leading spaces.